# How to build database schema for post-search filtering

Tags: database, database-design, data-structures, database-schema

I want to add post-search filtering to an e-commerce search function. Currently data exists like this:

Products (with BrandID)
Brands (foreign key to BrandID in products table)
ProductDietType (junction table for products and diet types)
DietTypes (various product diet types)
ProductDepartment (junction table for products and departments)
Departments

I want to add post-search filters where users can select multiple brands, departments, diet types to narrow the result set.

All I can think is to code like this:

if (none) ...
if (brand) ...
if (department) ...
if (diet type) ...
if (brand and department) ...
if (brand and diet type) ...
if (department and diet type) ...
if (brand and department and diet type) ...

I know this is wrong. as it's not very extensible: every time you add a new filter you double the number of code branches.

How would you go about coding this neatly and extensibly - so if I wanted to add another filter - e.g. country of origin - I could do so relatively painlessly.

I'm coding in C# and use SQL Server 2008.

Any help much appreciated.

Jon

Comment: The term to search under is "faceted".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a generic approach to product attributes. All possible filter criteria are called attributes (such as "Department #1"), grouped by attribute types (such as "Departments").

Such a model has pros and cons. For instance: How to guarantee that a product belongs to exactly one brand, when brand is just one of those attributes? This is a negative aspect of the model. The most positive aspect is: It doesn't matter whether you talk of a product's brand, diet type, department or whatever, they are equally just products' attributes you can filter by. It's easy to add more attributes without the hassle of having to change the filter code.

**Table attribute_type**

```
id | text
1  | 'Brand'
2  | 'Diet type'
3  | 'Department'
```

**Table attribute**

```
id | id_attribute_type | text
1  | 1                 | 'The Salad Makers'
2  | 1                 | 'Gorgeous Food'
3  | 1                 | 'Great Meals'
4  | 2                 | 'No fat'
5  | 2                 | 'Low carb'
6  | 2                 | 'No lactose'
7  | 3                 | 'Department 1'
8  | 4                 | 'Department 2'
```

**Table product_attribute**

```
id_product | id_attribute
1          | 1
1          | 4
1          | 5
1          | 7
2          | 2
2          | 4
2          | 6
2          | 7
```

Say you select all products with the word green in their title:

```
select * from products where upper(name) like '%GREEN%';
```

Additionally you need all filters associated with the selected products:

```
select at.id as at_id, at.text as at_text, a.id as a_id, a.text as a_text
from product_attribute pa
join attribute a on a.id = pa.id_attribute
join attribute_type at on at.id = a.id_attribute_type
where pa.id_product in (select id from products where upper(name) like '%GREEN%');
```

If the 'GREEN' products happen to be product 1 and 2 then you get:

- 'Brand' (1)

  - 'The Salad Makers' (1)
  - 'Gorgeous Food' (2)
- 'Diet type' (2)

  - 'No fat' (4)
  - 'Low carbonate' (5)
  - 'No lactose' (6)
- 'Department' (3)

  - 'Department 1' (7)

Now the user selects Brand = 'The Salad Makers' and 'Diet type' = 'No fat' or 'No lactose'. This makes:

```
select * 
from products
where upper(name) like '%GREEN%'
and id in 
(
  select id_product
  from product_attribute
  group by id_product
  having sum(case when id_attribute in (1) then 1 end) > 0 criteria for Brand
  and sum(case when id_attribute in (4,6) then 1 end) > 0 -- criteria for Diet type
);
```

You create such query just by adding a criteria line per used attribute type (1 Brand and 2 Diet Type here) with an IN clause containing the selected attributes.

Such a model can get more sophisticated. For example there might be some filters you would relate with OR (all products of either brand x *or* y), and others with AND (all products that are both sweet *and* sour).

Well, you get the idea. I don't know if you find this appropriate for what you are doing. It's just an idea. And as said, it has pros, but it also has cons.

You might also decide for a mixed concept (such as: main attributes like the brand stay real columns whereas other attributes go to the attributes table).

Comment: Many thanks for this answer. I'd had some similar thoughts, but am very grateful you took the time to expound the concept. I think I will keep the data structure I have as it is more formal, but will run a routine to extract that data into this attributes table which is used solely for search filtering. Also, when I need to check against potentially many values, I usually use an integer table type like this: @AttributeIDs integer_list_tbltype then use it like this: (pa.AttributeID IN (SELECT n FROM @AttributeIDs)))